# Unstaging and untracking in GIT

Tags: git, git-reset

I staged a file and to unstage it, I used git reset.

But instead of unstaging the file, it takes the file in 'untracked' status.

Why is it doing so?

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `reset` a file using `git reset`, that file is returned to the state it is in HEAD.  In the case where the file is not in HEAD (not committed to the git repository), a reset will return the file to `untracked` status.

If you wish for a new file to be treated as though it is tracked, you can use the `git add -N` command to mark the file with *intent to add*.

```
git add -N <file>
```

> --intent-to-add
>   Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for the path is placed in the index with no content. This is useful for, among other things, showing the unstaged content of such files with git diff and committing them with git commit -a.

Answer (score 3):

IF the file was not previously tracked, then unstaging it (meaning removing it from the index) would list it again as untracked.

Since [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) does reset the index entries for that file at HEAD, and that file was not part of HEAD, it is untracked.